# vscode add a line comment in an HTML file abnormal {{/* */}}

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, comments

I am trying Visual Studio Code lately and i've noticed that when i try to add a line comment in an HTML file (using Ctrl+/ or Ctrl+K Ctrl+C) instead of this: `<!-- -->`, i get this `{{/* */}}`.

I don't know which extension change it.
How to make a normal html comment?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bif8v.png)

Comment: do you have many extensions installed?

Comment: yes, i have 49 extensions

Comment: how many of them are HTML related? You could deactivate them one by one and check if it works. If you found the extension that causes the problem, and you dont need it, uninstall it

Comment: disable them all and try again, then enable them one at a time

Comment: do you know a language/HTML variant that use `{{/* */}}`, what is the languageId (lower right status bar) of the file

Comment: ...well i hope some know which language use {{/* */}} for comment, then i may find the related extension faster

Comment: THANK you very much! it shows`Golang HTML Template`. It's for golang generate code by `.tpl`.

Comment: In the future, don't disable them all and enable them one-by-one, use the `Bisect` command instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the languageId (lower right status bar) of the file

I recently write golang and install `casualjim.gotemplate`, this extension recognized html to tpl, then use the wrong comment.
I click languageId (lower right status bar), `select right language mode`: `html`, then it works normal.